# Convert string into an array with certain format

Tags: php, arrays, split

How can you convert a string that contains your first and last name and sometimes middle name into an array with this format?

```
customFunction('Chris Morris');
  // array('firstname' => 'Chris',     'lastname' => 'Morris')
customFunction('Chris D. Morris');
  // array('firstname' => 'Chris D.', 'lastname' => 'Morris')
customFunction('Chris');
  // array('firstname' => 'Chris',  'lastname' => '')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
function splitName($name){
  $name = explode(" ",$name);
  $lastname= count($name)>1 ? array_pop($name):"";
 return array("firstname"=>implode(" ",$name), "lastname"=>$lastname);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try this:

```
 <?php
    $arr = 'Chris D. Morris';
   function customFunction($str){
    $str = trim($str);
    $lastSpace = strrpos($str," ");
    if($lastSpace == 0){
        $first = $str;
        return array('firstname' => $first, 'lastname' => $last);
    }else{
    $first = substr($str, 0, $lastSpace);
    $last = substr($str,$lastSpace);
    return array('firstname' => $first, 'lastname' => $last);
    }
}
    $got = customFunction($arr);
    print_r($got);
    ?>
```

hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
function parseName($input) {

    $retval = array();
    $retval['firstname'] = '';
    $retval['lastname'] = '';

    $words = explode(' ', $input);
    if (count($words) == 1) {
        $retval['firstname'] = $words[0];
    } elseif (count($words) > 1) {
        $retval['lastname'] = array_pop($words);
        $retval['firstname'] = implode(' ', $words);
    }

    return $retval;
}
```

Comment: I get Array to string conversion when passing the string to the function.

Comment: Just fixed it... Although I see two other solutions which are much shorter. I'd use one of them.